# mongodb, pymongo, aggregate gives strange output (something about cursor)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying get a list of people with the most entries in my database.

```
print db.points.aggregate(
   [
      {
         "$group":
                    {
                       "_id": "$created.user", 
                       "count":{"$sum":1}
                    }
      },
      {
         "$sort":
                   {"count":-1}
      }
   ]
)
```

An entry looks like this :

```
{
   u'id': u'342902', 
   u'_id': ObjectId('555af76a029d3b1b0ff9a4be'), 
   u'type': u'node', 
   u'pos': [48.9979746, 8.3719741], 
   u'created': {
                  u'changeset': u'7105928', 
                  u'version': u'4', 
                  u'uid': u'163673', 
                  u'timestamp': u'2011-01-27T18:05:54Z', 
                  u'user': u'Free_Jan'
               }
}
```

I know that `created.user` exists and is otherwise accessible.

Still the output i get is:

`<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x02ADD6B0>`

Shouldn't I get a sorted list ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The result of an aggregation query is a cursor, as for a regular `find` query. In case of `pymongo` the `CommandCursor` is iterable, thus you are able to do any of the following:

```
cursor = db.points.aggregate(...)

# Option 1
print(list(cursor))

# Option 2
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

***Note:*** as [arun noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333020/mongodb-pymongo-aggregate-gives-strange-output-something-about-cursor/30333619#comment51860764_30333619), in both cases, i.e. after you create a list out of the cursor, or iterate in the for loop, you will not be able to re-iterate over the cursor. In that case the first option becomes better, if you want to use it in future, as you can use the obtained list as much as you want, because it is in the memory already.
The reason of not being able to reiterate is that the cursor is actually on the server, and it send the data chunk-by-chunk, and after it has sent you all the data (or the server terminates) the cursor gets destroyed.

Comment: Just as caution (though you clearly mention them as two options): after getting the list, you cannot again iterate on the cursor. You have to iterate on the list.

Comment: Using list(cursor) doesn't seem to work nowadays. It gives *** Error in argument: '(cursor)'