# How do you use $count?

Tags: python, mongodb, count

The mongodb documentation said to use `db.collection.aggregate([{$count: "timers"}])` to count how many documents are in the collection "timers", but it says that `$count` is invalid syntax. Is there a way to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in quotes `"$count"`

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ "$count" : "timers"}])
```

Comment: the code runs now but its giving <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x000001CB946CF490> now instead of just a number

Comment: @Archiblade `print(list(cursor))` Read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333020/