# Why does the python list parsing work differently inline?

Tags: python, pymongo

In our project we try to work with the output of an aggregation, which is more challenging than expected. The following code throws an `IndexError`, even though our object looks (when using the `print` command) like this `[{'_id': None, 'sum': 2700}]`.

```py
output = get_mongo_collection().aggregate([
        {'$match': {'topic_name': topic, 'internal_id': self.internal_id }},
        {'$group': {'_id': None, 'sum': {'$sum': '$payload.val'}}}])

print(list(output)[0]["sum"])
```

Things we tried and were confused by

```py
out = list(output)
print(out)  # [{'_id': None, 'sum': 2700}]
print(len(out))  # 1
print(out[0]["sum"])  # 2700

print(list(output))  # []
print(len(list(output)))  # 0
```

It seems that this has something to do with the inline `list` keyword usage. Maybe this has something to do with the pymongo aggregation object? Because trying to reproduce it with a list created manually, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Looks like `get_mongo_collection().aggregate` returns something like a generator which can only be iterate once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb, pymongo, aggregate gives strange output (something about cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333020/mongodb-pymongo-aggregate-gives-strange-output-something-about-cursor)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM when parsing the return object to a list, I expect it to behave like a list. If it is not possible to convert, I expect an error. No this doesn't answer my question because the solution provided there is exactly the thing that throws the error here.

Comment: you could edit the question to have correct variable names, it's called put_out but then also out?

Comment: Abdul might also be correct in which case you just need to use the out object or run the aggregation again (since after you change it to a list, it is gone)

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the hint, I adjusted the variable names. Yes I can use the out object, that is not a problem. But I still would like to know why this issue occurs, because theoretically they should be the same in my understanding.

Comment: It has nothing to do with inline usage, it's because you can only use `output` once, every time after that it will be empty. If you reverse your code you'll see the opposite result.

Comment: @MarkRansom But shouldn't my initial code run then? Also if I just execute the last two prints it shows the same, which I suppose wouldn't be the case in your theory?

Comment: Yes your initial code should have worked, I don't have an explanation for that. Which is why I didn't leave an answer.