# How can I convert my aggregate result set data type into the correct data type for Jinja 2?

Tags: python, jinja2

How can I convert my aggregate result set data type into the correct data type for Jinja 2?

I can't figure out what the difference is between what a MongoDB .find() returns and what .aggregate() returns. The .find works as expected. the .aggregate doesn't. I'm sure my problem is converting the aggregate result set into the correct data type to be rendered in Jinja 2.

Python Code:

```
###################################################################################
# The Python code for the find() operations works as expected
###################################################################################
findResults = current_app.db.inventory.find({"account_id": session["user_id"]})
findResults_form = [InventoryDetailClass(**inventory) for inventory in findResults ]

print(findResults)
print(findResults_form)

return render_template('Inventorylist.html',findResults_form = findResults_form )

###################################################################################
# I get the desired result set from the aggregate operation see print(aggregateResults) below
# But the aggregateResults_form is empty
###################################################################################
aggregateResults = current_app.db.inventory.aggregate([{
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'contacts', 
        'localField': 'seller_id', 
        'foreignField': '_id', 
        'as': 'contacts_docs'
        }
    }, {
    '$project': {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "item": "$item",
        "quantity": "$quantity",
        "price": "$askingPrice",
        "sellerName": "$contacts_docs.contactName"
        }
    }])

# >> I believe this is where my problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
aggregateResults_form = [InvListClass(**aggList) for aggList in aggregateResults]

print(aggregateResults)
for data in aggregateResults:
    print(f'aggregateResults: {data}\n')

print(aggregateResults_form)

return render_template('Inventorylist.html',aggregateResults_form = aggregateResults_form )
```

Find - Output from print function:

```
print(findResults):
        <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000021CE4767E90>

print(findResults_form):
    InventoryDetailClass(
    _id='d61a84c3d2bb4f548a31aff39deb12de', 
    item='Dresser', 
    quantity=1, 
    price='500', 
    sellerName=''
    ), 
    InventoryDetailClass(
    _id='eef188ade2fe4384aeff201893b006ec', 
    item='Car', 
    quantity=1, 
    price='2500', 
    sellerName=''
    )
```

Aggregate - Output from print function:

```
print(aggregateResults):
    <pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x000001CED9CC0610>

for data in aggregateResults:
    print(f'aggregateResults: {data}\n')

aggregateResults: 
{
'_id': 'd61a84c3d2bb4f548a31aff39deb12de', 
'item': 'Dresser', 
'quantity': 1, 
'price': '500', 
'sellerName': ['Bob Smith']
}

aggregateResults: 
{
'_id': 
'eef188ade2fe4384aeff201893b006ec', 
'item': 'Car', 
'quantity': 1, 
'price': '2500', 
'sellerName': ['Jane Doe']}

aggregateResults_form:
    []
```

Jinja2 Code:

```
{% for i in aggregateResults_form %}
<tr>
   <td id='{{ i._id }}'>{{ i.item }}</td>
   <td id='{{ i._id }}'>{{ i.quantity }}</td>
   <td id='{{ i._id }}'>{{ i.price }}</td>
   <td id='{{ i._id }}'>{{ i.sellerName }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in this post:
[mongodb, pymongo, aggregate gives strange output (something about cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333020/mongodb-pymongo-aggregate-gives-strange-output-something-about-cursor)

The key point from this post is:

> Note: as arun noticed, in both cases, i.e. after you create a list out
> of the cursor, or iterate in the for loop, you will not be able to
> re-iterate over the cursor. In that case the first option becomes
> better, if you want to use it in future, as you can use the obtained
> list as much as you want, because it is in the memory already. The
> reason of not being able to reiterate is that the cursor is actually
> on the server, and it send the data chunk-by-chunk, and after it has
> sent you all the data (or the server terminates) the cursor gets
> destroyed.

Once I removed my print functions and my for loops in my Python code, my results showed up on my web page.